# Github page not working completely

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I've created my github.io page but it's graphics are not loading completely and browser display a warning: opera has blocked content of this page which comes from insecure sources.

How to fix this?

my github page: https://msdeep14.github.io

repo link: https://github.com/msdeep14/msdeep14.github.io

Comment: what kind of graphics you want?

Comment: @Siddharth actually I dont have knowledge of html, css

I had taken this layout from here https://github.com/biomadeira/sustain

Comment: i understand your concern, but this platform in not to get people to write code for you, learn html, it is easy

Answer (score 1):

Page URLs in https should NOT link to http resources.

You might have hard-coded 'http' only values for your assets like css and images. Debug your page in inspector and see network log.

Press F12.

Comment: I didn't get your answer, and I dont have much knowledge of html, css. I just used template from here https://github.com/biomadeira/sustain

Comment: I made the changes but error not fixed. should I change http in  this also - <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">  ?

Answer (score 1):

What Bimal already was trying to say: Your page is served via HTTPS (that is, over an encrypted connection). To ensure that *everything* is secure in such a case, browsers require all resources, like CSS and JavaScript files and images to be also served via HTTPS.

The easiest solution in your case is to replace all occurrences of `http:` with `https:` and check if the page still works. If it doesn't, then some file is presumably not available via HTTPS. In that case, you might need to add it to your Github repo and change the link accordingly.

Comment: I made the changes, still error is not fixed. How to check which file is missing? But how can file be missing if repo which I cloned, for that the .io page works fine.

Comment: I get an error "Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery". You should try moving the `<script>` tag including jQuery (the second at the bottom of the page) up above the first one at the bottom, which includes the Bootstrap JS files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `https://` in the URLs of the external elements used by your page (images, scripts, stylesheets) as other answers suggest.

But you can do even better by using protocol-relative URLs, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//msdeep14.github.io/static/css/syntax.css" />
```

For URLs of resources located on your own domain you can even use host-relative URLs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/syntax.css" />
```

(but you have to stick to the first form for URLs outside your domain).

Both the above solutions work (since forever) with all browsers. The browser compute the complete URLs using the URL of the current page as base. This way, when the page is loaded using `HTTP`, the external resources are also loaded using `HTTP` and when it is loaded using `HTTPS`, the resources are also loaded using `HTTPS` and the browsers do not display annoying warnings.